# Auto increment appended class or ID number in JS function parameter and target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if how to modify a function that takes a class name + appended number and apply to another class with a corresponding number.

What I have in place for now is:

```
function hideSect()
{
    if($('.trigger').is(":checked"))   
        $(".condition").hide();
    else
        $(".condition").show();
}
```

How would I modify it so that it can dynamically take trigger1 and apply to condition1, trigger2 to condition2, etc.

Related HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" onchange="hideSect()"><label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span></label>
<div class="condition">
    <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML layout look like? Could be a lot simpler.

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML? Could you post it?

Comment: Question updated with related html

Answer (score 0):

With that HTML layout, you can just use CSS

```css
input.trigger:checked + label + div {
     display: none; 
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
```

Other than that you could just find the next sibling that has the class condition.

```js
$(".trigger").on("change", function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".condition").first().toggle(!this.checked);
    
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
```

If you can not rely on html layout, than use a data attribute

```js
$(".trigger").on("change", function(){
    var cb = $(this),
        selector = cb.data("toggles");
    $(selector).first().toggle(!this.checked);
    
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" data-toggles="#f1" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition" id="f1">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" data-toggles="#f2" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition" id="f2">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
```

And if you really need to use the ids, you can do something like

```js
$(".trigger").on("change", function(){
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $("#f" + num).toggle(!this.checked);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" ID="c1" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition" id="f1">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="c2" >
<label><span>I do not wish to furnish this information.</span>
</label>
<div class="condition" id="f2">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!--Conditional content in here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, small issue I might run into with this is, sometimes the condition is not not next to the trigger. This code is part of a multipage form I'm making. For example, sometimes I'll have a situation in which a yes/no question on page 1 will dictate whether or not a question on page 5 will show up. Or even if page 6 will show up at all

Comment: So I would use data attributes instead of parsing numbers from ids.

Comment: Edited with other options.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, can this code be used to work with radio button selections as well as checkboxes?

Comment: Did you try it?